# Google Geo API (Latitude + Longitude)

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

I am currently trying to solve my users location from the GEO I get with html5, now im trying to fetch the formatted address from the Google API.

I have done this:

```
function LatLong($Latitude, $Longitude) {


    $Url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$Latitude,$Longitude&sensor=true";


    //send request:
    $Client = curl_init($Url);

    //Set options:
    curl_setopt($Client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //query the API and fetch results:
    $Response = curl_exec($Client);

    //decode the response:
    return  json_decode($Response);

}
```

Now, to get the full result, i tried this just to see if it worked:

```
print_r(LatLong($_COOKIE['latitude'], $_COOKIE['longitude'])->results);
```

I do get a result:

```
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "4",
           "short_name" : "4",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Neuwerk - Cuxhaven",
           "short_name" : "Neuwerk - Cuxhaven",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Hamburg-Insel Neuwerk",
           "short_name" : "Hamburg-Insel Neuwerk",
           "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Hamburg",
           "short_name" : "Hamburg",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Hamburg",
           "short_name" : "Hamburg",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Tyskland",
           "short_name" : "DE",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "27499",
           "short_name" : "27499",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Neuwerk - Cuxhaven 4, 27499 Hamburg, Tyskland",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 53.91403529999999,
           "lng" : 8.4899886
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.91538428029149,
              "lng" : 8.491337580291502
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.91268631970849,
              "lng" : 8.488639619708497
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJrT-2jXcZtEcRv91jn7XQhcQ",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  }
```

I want to print `formatted_address`
and i tried to do it like this:

```
print_r(LatLong($_COOKIE['latitude'], $_COOKIE['longitude'])->results->formatted_address);
```

But I don't get anything, what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in the question, `results` is an array. Which means you probably want to access the first element before taking `formatted_address`.

Try this:

```
print_r(LatLong($_COOKIE['latitude'], $_COOKIE['longitude'])->results[0]->formatted_address);
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly! i didnt realize i had to go at it this way. will accept answer in 7 mins :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $string = file_get_contents('./string.json');
  $json = json_decode($string);
```

if you want to have items: :

```
foreach ($json['items'] as $address)
{
    echo "items:". $address['address'] ."\n";
};
```

anyway if you are not sure about how an array is built you could print it via:

```
print_r($json);
```

which will print:

Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [address] => W 7th Ave
                )

```
        [1] => Array
            (
                [address] => W 8th St
            )
    )
```

)

now you found out that $json contains just an array (items) of two array, then, if you loop it, you will get that array which is printed in your example. As explained above you need to go one step deeper by looping the elements in your items array and print their address element.

here is the complete script: http://pastie.org/2275879